# How can I set up RSpec for performance testing 'on the side'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, fixtures, performance-testing

We are using RSpec in a rails project for unit testing. I would like to set up some performance tests in RSpec, but do it in a way as to not disrupt the 'regular' features and fixtures.

Ideally I'd be able to tag my performance specs in a certain way such that they are not run by default. 
Then when I specify to run these specs explicitly it will load a different set of fixtures (it makes sense to do performance testing with a much larger and more 'production-like' dataset).

Is this possible? It seems like it should be.

Has anyone set up something like this? How did you go about it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I managed to get what I was looking for via the following:

```
# Exclude :performance tagged specs by default
config.filter_run_excluding :performance => true

# When we're running a performance test load the test fixures:
config.before(:all, :performance => true) do
  # load performance fixtures
  require 'active_record/fixtures'
  ActiveRecord::Fixtures.reset_cache
  ActiveRecord::Fixtures.create_fixtures('spec/perf_fixtures', File.basename("products.yml", '.*'))
  ActiveRecord::Fixtures.create_fixtures('spec/perf_fixtures', File.basename("ingredients.yml", '.*'))
end

# define an rspec helper for takes_less_than
require 'benchmark'
RSpec::Matchers.define :take_less_than do |n|
  chain :seconds do; end
  match do |block|
    @elapsed = Benchmark.realtime do
      block.call
    end
    @elapsed <= n
  end
end

# example of a performance test
describe Api::ProductsController, "API Products controller", :performance do
  it "should fetch all the products reasonably quickly" do
    expect do
      get :index, :format => :json
    end.to take_less_than(60).seconds
  end
end
```

But I tend to agree with Marnen's point that this isn't really the best idea for performance testing.

Answer (score 9):

I created [rspec-benchmark](https://github.com/piotrmurach/rspec-benchmark) Ruby gem for writing performance tests in RSpec. It has many expectations for testing speed, resources usage, and scalability.

For example, to test how fast your code is:

```
expect { ... }.to perform_under(60).ms
```

Or to compare with another implementation:

```
expect { ... }.to perform_faster_than { ... }.at_least(5).times
```

Or to test computational complexity:

```
expect { ... }.to perform_logarithmic.in_range(8, 100_000)
```

Or to see how many objects get allocated:

```
expect {
  _a = [Object.new]
  _b = {Object.new => 'foo'}
}.to perform_allocation({Array => 1, Object => 2}).objects
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do performance testing, why not run New Relic or something with a snapshot of production data? You don't really need different specs for that, I think.

Comment: Mainly I was wondering how feasible it would be to automate performance testing. So that a code change that introduced a significant negative performance impact would 'trip' a test than asserts that a certain function can run in eg less than 30 seconds.

Comment: You could do that, but I'm not sure how practically useful it would be, especially since RSpec is best when not testing user-facing stuff, and performance is user-facing. I suppose you could use Cucumber instead of RSpec for your performance tests, but I tend to think this is best left to New Relic.

Comment: That is called profiling, not performance testing. Performance testing should ensure that a piece of code runs within a desired amount of time, given a certain context, before the new code goes into production.

Comment: @aledalgrande For that kind of performance testing, I'd advise Cucumber.